# how to get text using document queryselector without using xpath?

Tags: javascript, console

I have the following structure in HTML:

```
<strong>
    <a name^:"id-001"> </a>
    "text to get"
</strong>
```

I'm using `document.querySelector('strong a[name^="id-"])` 
which will return the element `<a name="id-001"> </a>`

However I'm trying to get the text using:
`document.querySelector('strong a[name^="id-"]).textContent`
which will return a `""`.

How would I get the strong `"text to get"`?

Comment: it will return the anchor element, the text is outside of the anchor element

Comment: I'm trying to get "text to get" when there is an anchor with id starting with "id-001" otherwise I'll get all strongs.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('strong').forEach( function(entry) {console.log(entry)})   
                                                                                                                                    this will get me all strongs....including strong without anchor.